# How to fix this "Key Error:t" i got while i was writing a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

**I wrote this code and then i took an error which i wrote below. There is a while loop which lets me take the data which is limited by 1000 columns as much time as i described in reapeat_rounds variable but when i tried to use that loop, a "keyerror:t" raises.If i do reapeat_rounds = 0, i dont get such error but if i do that, it means while loop wont work and if while loop works, i get the error please help me to solve that error, thank you.**

```
class Binance:

    def __init__(self):

        self.base = 'https://api.binance.com'

        self.endpoints = {
            "order": '/api/v3/order',
            "testOrder": '/api/v3/order/test',
            "allOrders": '/api/v3/allOrders',
            "klines": '/api/v3/klines',
            "exchangeInfo": '/api/v3/exchangeInfo'
        }

        self.headers = {"X-MBX-APIKEY": binance_keys['api_key']}

    def GetLongerSymbolData(self, symbol:str, interval:str, limit:int=1000, end_time=False):
        # Basicall, we will be calling the GetSymbolData as many times as we need 
        # in order to get all the historical data required (based on the limit parameter)
        # and we'll be merging the results into one long dataframe.

        repeat_rounds = 1
        if limit > 1000:
            repeat_rounds = int(limit/1000)
        initial_limit = limit % 1000
        if initial_limit == 0:
            initial_limit = 1000
        # First, we get the last initial_limit candles, starting at end_time and going
        # backwards (or starting in the present moment, if end_time is False)
        df = self.GetSymbolData(symbol, interval, limit=initial_limit, end_time=end_time)
        while repeat_rounds > 0:
            # Then, for every other 1000 candles, we get them, but starting at the beginning
            # of the previously received candles.
            df2 = self.GetSymbolData(symbol, interval, limit=1000, end_time=df['time'[0]])
            df = df2.append(df, ignore_index = True)
            repeat_rounds = repeat_rounds - 1

        return df

Data = Binance()

m = Data.GetLongerSymbolData('BTCUSDT','1h')

print(m)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\orhan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 't'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/orhan/Desktop/DW/Data.py", line 101, in <module>
    m = Data.GetLongerSymbolData('BTCUSDT','1h')
  File "c:/Users/orhan/Desktop/DW/Data.py", line 47, in GetLongerSymbolData
    df2 = self.GetSymbolData(symbol, interval, limit=1000, end_time=df['time'[0]])
  File "C:\Users\orhan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\orhan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 't'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to replace the line

```py
df2 = self.GetSymbolData(symbol, interval, limit=1000, end_time=df['time'[0]])
```

with something like

```py
df2 = self.GetSymbolData(symbol, interval, limit=1000, end_time=df['time'][0])
```

?

Here, the `[0]` is applied on the `'time'` string, which essentially just results in the string `'t'` as a key for your DataFrame.